# Fiddler: is it possible to compress/gzip the request body?

Tags: request, fiddler, compression

Great tool, does everything I need. Love its Transform tab that allows compression of the response. But what about request? Seems like a simple thing but I don't see that functionality. Am I missing something?

Fiddler Web Debugger, V2.3.4.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a bit of script to compress the request body. Click Rules > Customize Rules, and add something like this:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session){
  if (oSession.requestBodyBytes != null && oSession.requestBodyBytes.Length>0){
    oSession.requestBodyBytes = Utilities.GzipCompress(oSession.requestBodyBytes);
    oSession["Content-Length"] = oSession.requestBodyBytes.Length.ToString();
    oSession["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
  }
```

However, I'm not aware of any servers that actually support compressed requests. There's no good way for a server to signal that it supports compressed requests, and [Zip Bomb attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb) are a real threat for servers.

Comment: Super. Thanks! I'll try that. Zip Bomb reference is relevant. However this is not public facing API and we need to transport megabytes of XML data so zipping is a quick and simple way of reducing payload size.

Comment: FWIW, if you're doing this in a private environment, you might try using LZMA compression instead of GZIP. LZMA can be more efficient in terms of transfer size.

Comment: One example of a place that accepts (requires) gzip is the IRS for electronic A2A submission.